# CTE с условием внутри

Tags: sql-server

Использую CTE, в зависимости от условия содержимое должно быть разным, например:

```
With Users(Id)
As
(
Select IIF(@UserId = 1,1,0)
)
```

Проблема в следующем, вместо 1 и 0, мне нужно вернуть результат запроса, например:

```
With Users(Id)
As
(
Select IIF(@UserId = 1,(Select Id from Users2),(Select Id from Clients))
)
```

Но когда эти запросы возвращают больше одного значения, вылетает ошибка.

Думаю, должно быть какое-то другое решение, но мне ничего придумать не удается.

P.s. использование CTE принципиально.

**Обновление**

Мне необходимы именно все данные, к примеру, при обращении в дальнейшем к Users, в зависимости от параметра @UserId мне возвращались id'шники пользователей или клиентов.

Что-то вроде такого мне нужно:

```
With Users(Id)
As
(
    IF @UserId = 1
        BEGIN
        Select top 10 Id from Clients
        END
)
```

Но только CTE такой синтаксис не воспринимает.

Comment: Что то вроде такого мне нужно:

With Users(Id)
As
(
 IF @UserId = 1
  BEGIN
  Select top 10 Id from Billing.Clients
  END
)

Но только CTE такой синтаксис не воспринимает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With Users(Id) As
(   Select Id from Users2
    Where @UserId = 1
    Union
    Select Id from Clients
    Where @UserId is null or not @UserId = 1
)
```